# Select elements from a nested structure that match a condition in Clojure

Tags: clojure, specter

I recently discovered the [Specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) library that provides data-structure navigation and transformation functions and is written in Clojure.

Implementing some of its API as a learning exercise seemed like a good idea. Specter implements an API taking a function and a nested structure as arguments and returns a vector of elements from the nested structure that satisfies the function like below:

`(select (walker number?) [1 :a {:b 2}])` => `[1 2]`

Below is my attempt at implementing a function with similar API:

```
(defn select-walker [afn ds]
  (vec (if (and (coll? ds) (not-empty ds))
         (concat (select-walker afn (first ds)) 
                 (select-walker afn (rest ds)))
         (if (afn ds) [ds]))))
```

`(select-walker number? [1 :a {:b 2}])` => `[1 2]`

I have tried implementing `select-walker` by using [list comprehension](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for), [looping](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop), and using [cons](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cons) and [conj](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj). In all these cases
the return value was a nested list instead of a flat vector of elements.

Yet my implementation does not seem like idiomatic Clojure and has poor time and space complexity.

```
(time (dotimes [_ 1000] (select (walker number?) (range 100))))
"Elapsed time: 19.445396 msecs"

(time (dotimes [_ 1000] (select-walker number? (range 100))))
"Elapsed time: 237.000334 msecs"
```

Notice that my implementation is about 12 times slower than Specter's implementation.

I have three questions on the implemention of `select-walker`.

1. Is a tail-recursive implementaion of `select-walker` possible?
2. Can `select-walker` be written in more idiomatic Clojure?
3. Any hints to make `select-walker` execute faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. there are at least two possibilities to make it tail recursive. First one is to process data in loop like this:

   ```
   (defn select-walker-rec [afn ds]
     (loop [res [] ds ds]
       (cond (empty? ds) res
             (coll? (first ds)) (recur res 
                                       (doall (concat (first ds) 
                                                      (rest ds))))
             (afn (first ds)) (recur (conj res (first ds)) (rest ds))
             :else (recur res (rest ds)))))
   ```

   in repl:

   ```
   user> (select-walker-rec number? [1 :a {:b 2}])
   [1 2]

   user> user> (time (dotimes [_ 1000] (select-walker-rec number? (range 100))))
   "Elapsed time: 19.428887 msecs"
   ```

   (simple select-walker works about 200ms for me)

   the second one (slower though, and more suitable for more difficult tasks) is to use `zippers`:

   ```
   (require '[clojure.zip :as z])

   (defn select-walker-z [afn ds]
     (loop [res [] curr (z/zipper coll? seq nil ds)]
       (cond (z/end? curr) res
             (z/branch? curr) (recur res (z/next curr))
             (afn (z/node curr)) (recur (conj res (z/node curr))
                                        (z/next curr))
             :else (recur res (z/next curr)))))

   user> (time (dotimes [_ 1000] (select-walker-z number? (range 100))))
   "Elapsed time: 219.015153 msecs"
   ```

   this one is really slow, since zipper operates on more complex structures. It's great power brings unneeded overhead to this simple task.
2. the most idiomatic approach i guess, is to use `tree-seq`:

   ```
   (defn select-walker-t [afn ds]
     (filter #(and (not (coll? %)) (afn %))
             (tree-seq coll? seq ds)))

   user> (time (dotimes [_ 1000] (select-walker-t number? (range 100))))
   "Elapsed time: 1.320209 msecs"
   ```

   it is incredibly fast, as it produces a lazy sequence of results. In fact you should realize its data for the fair test:

   ```
   user> (time (dotimes [_ 1000] (doall (select-walker-t number? (range 100)))))
   "Elapsed time: 53.641014 msecs"
   ```

   one more thing to notice about this variant, is that it's not tail recursive, so it would fail in case of really deeply nested structures (maybe i'm mistaken, but i guess it's about couple of thousands levels of nesting), still it's suitable for the most cases.

Comment: Thanks. I liked the way `select-walker-rec` recurses through the nested ds. Similar to depth first traversal.